# Usage of "since" in "Since the last release, we have integrated feature X"

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

Does the following sentence imply that X is included in the last release or not?

> *Since* the last release, we have integrated feature X.

Comment: In a word, yes ...

Comment: @carlo that's not helpful. OP--your sentence implies that a new feature was added to the current release that was NOT in the previous

Comment: @simchona: I also thought it implied the last release contained the feature, but when I asked they said, no, it was **since** the last release, so it'll be in the next release... which made me wonder which is correct.

Comment: On three more reads, that sentence is inherently ambiguous.

Comment: The feature is clearly not in the "last release". The question is whether the "last release" is the current release or the release before the current release. Both cases are possible.

Comment: Then, what is the difference between "since the ..." and "after the ..." I'm confused, sorry.

Comment: @PeterShor: Er... "last release" was my own wording. They said something like "the June release" (which happened to be the latest one), so that part was not supposed to be ambiguous.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Yeah that's pretty much my question.

Comment: I'm not native, but, presumably, your example could be rewritten in this way: "From the time of the last ..." If so, it is clear that X was already included in the last release.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: lol, but they clearly said **"since"**, which is the point of this question. What you're suggesting I do would be defeating the entire question.

Comment: The difference between *since* and *after* (when they are used for time) is roughly the same as difference between the present perfect and the simple past. *Since* often means the time between the stated time and the current time, and *after* means some point past the stated time. In this case, *since* and *after* mean essentially the same thing (*since* might imply that it took them more time to add it, while *after* might imply that they added it in response to something that happened at the last release).

Comment: In fact, if you look at the examples given in [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary,](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/) since is always used with a perfect tense, and after with the simple past or the future. (Although it's not a strict rule that you use *since* with perfect tenses and *after* otherwise.)

Comment: @Peter Shor Thank you for these interesting considerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. The word *since* means having occurred in the span of time that starts **after** an event on up until the present.

The example above would insinuate that there is either a subsequent patch, or that the feature is complete and will be released in the future.

Answer (score 2):

It implies that feature X has been added *since* the last/previous/June release.  (Otherwise, what's the point of mentioning it?)

Comment: Yes, I agree. +1 - one question: do you know what part of speech "since" here is?

Comment: Is there someone that knows what part of speech "since" is in current OP example? I'm asking as combread ninja, probably, is no longer on line.

Comment: It's a preposition

Comment: Why is this just repeating the phrase in my question? (Regarding your second sentence: "The point of mentioning it" was that I asked if/when the feature was added.)

Comment: @Mehrdad. I think you misinterpreted Cornbread Ninja's words; he meant to say that, if the feature were included, there wouldn't be any point in mentioning the fact that it was released *since* the last release. He was not referring to your words, but to the company's or the developer's words.

Comment: @Paola: Oooh... interesting.. but then, what would they say in that case?

Comment: @Mehrdad. I guess FumbleFingers has supplied some interesting ways to clarify the sentence on the part of the initial speaker. I surely don't have anything better to offer.

Answer (score 1):

The *long* answer is that OP's cited usage of *"since"* is ambiguous. For example...

> I've loved her since I first met her.

...would always be taken to mean that the loving and the first meeting coincided (i.e. - *"since"* **includes** the time of the event mentioned). But...

> Since Styllou Christofi was executed in 1954, only one other woman has been executed in Britain.

...clearly **doesn't include** the 1954 execution in the scope of *"since"*.

To provide an unambiguous meaning you'd have to rephrase with something like *"As from"* (definitely includes the event), *"After"* (probably doesn't include the event), or *"At some time after"* (definitely doesn't include the event).

Comment: Since would only be ambiguous in this case if the statement had been made in the past-perfect tense: ie: *"this feature has been integrated since"*; the fact that past tense was used indicates that the event predated the time span.

Comment: @Bryan Agee: You already said that in your own answer, but I disagree.